# Bootstrap styling issues. Styles are completely broken in ie9

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

[image]

As you see from the image, the styling is completely messed up in IE9. I checked [bootstrap site](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/wiki/Browser-Compatibility) and it appears to be compatible with all browers.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYnQE.png link to img for bigger version.

Below is the code I have:

html page:

```
<html>

<head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    ...
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
        <form class="form-signin" id="frm_login">
            <fieldset>                                
                <input type="text" class="input-block-level" id="u" name="username" placeholder="Email address">
                <input type="password" class="input-block-level" id="p" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                <a href="https://www.otciq.com/otciq/forgotPassword">Forgot Password?</a>
                <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary submitButton" id="btn_login" type="button" value="Sign In"/>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

the css:

```
.form-signin
{
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 19px 29px 29px;
    margin: 0 auto 20px;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}

.form-signin .form-signin-heading,
.form-signin
{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-signin input[type="text"],
.form-signin input[type="password"]
{
    font-size: 16px;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding: 7px 9px;
}

.form-signin .submitButton,
.form-signin .submitButton:hover
{
    margin-left: 86px;
    background:#00A88F;
}

p {margin:20px 0;}
a {color:#666;}
a:hover {color: #333;}
```

What could be causing this problem?

ive tried all the settings i see in the ie9 debugger console. using ie9 browser mode, ie7 standard, ie8 standard looks similar to what i see in ff, ie9 standard completely breaks the styling. i was told to add  in the html, but that breaks the css on ff/chrome/ie9.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
<div id="container">
```

to

```
<div class="container">
```